# Object detection training job fails on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection

I am running a training job on GCP for object detection using my own dataset. My training job script is like this:

```
JOB_NAME=object_detection"_$(date +%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S)"
echo $JOB_NAME
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
        --job-dir=gs://$1 \
        --scale-tier BASIC_GPU \
        --runtime-version 1.12 \
        --packages $PWD/models/research/dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,$PWD/models/research/slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \
        --module-name $PWD/models/research/object_detection.model_main \
        --region europe-west1 \
        -- \
        --model_dir=gs://$1 \
        --pipeline_config_path=gs://$1/data/fast_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config
```

It fails at the following line :

```
python -m $PWD/models/research/object_detection.model_main --model_dir=gs://my-hand-detector --pipeline_config_path=gs://my-hand-detector/data/fast_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --job-dir gs://my-hand-detector/
/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Based on logs, this is the source of error which I have understood. Any help in this regard would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using model_main.py file from Tensorflow GitHub [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py). Using it, I have been able to replicate your error message. After troubleshooting, I successfully submitted the training job and could train the model properly.

In order to address your issue I suggest you to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md#starting-training-and-evaluation-jobs-on-google-cloud-ml-engine), taking special consideration to the following steps:

- Make sure to have an updated version of tensorflow (1.14 doesn’t include all necessary capabilities)
- Properly generate TFRecords from input data and upload them to GCS bucket
- Configure object detection pipeline (set the proper paths to data and label map)

In my case, I have reproduced the workflow using PASCAL VOC input data (See  [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md)).

---